# Password 'spatial' pattern?

Tags: passwords

While messing around with the [Cygnius Password Strength Test](https://apps.cygnius.net/passtest/) I noticed that if you enter a sequence like

```
wsdxcv
```

the test labels it as a "spatial" pattern — obviously because the keys are close together on a qwerty keyboard, if on different rows.

Googling around I can hardly find any mention of the idea, and I can't imagine it'd be especially common anyway (outside of one-handed passwords). Plus there may be multiple keyboard layouts to consider.

So the question is, are cracking algorithms actually likely to take this pattern into consideration?

Comment: It's not as uncommon as you want to think. I've seen it for production accounts.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This method of creating a password by pressing adjecant keys is called a *keyboard walk*. Password crackers kind of take this into account; they don't explicitly try keyboard walks, but the most common keyboard walks are contained in password dictionaries. So crackers will test for `qwerty`, not because it is a keyboard walk but because it is a common password.

There are some tools to create dictionaries with password walks:

- HashCat's [kwprocessor](https://github.com/hashcat/kwprocessor), a keyboard-walk generator with configureable basechars, keymap and routes.
- [passpat](https://digi.ninja/projects/passpat.php) can identify passwords that are keyboard walks.
- [Generating Keyboard Walks](http://frogstarworldc.com/2014/08/generating-keyboard-walks/), a blog post and software to create keyboard walks.

Comment: Nice to know there's another name for this pattern. Good answer, useful references.

Comment: I can also say, from personal experience, that keyboard walks are probably the easiest sort of password to shoulder surf.